# how to make the following jquery slider code slide automatically

Tags: jquery, html, slider

```
jQuery(function($) {'use strict',
    //#main-slider
    $(function(){
        $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
        });     
    });
});
```

Following is the html code where it is used:

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS code :)

Comment: You need to pass in the auto play option. Similar to what you have already done with the 'interval: 3000' option. Just add auto play underneath. Have a look at the docs for the carousel to see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try out following :

```
$(function(){
    $('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 3000,
        autoplay:true
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done by using below JQuery:

```
$('#main-slider.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 3000,
    cycle: true
});
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w2am9sgt/).

Hope it helps you.

Thanks